# Read temperature with MAX31855 Thermocouple Sensor on Windows IoT

Tags: c#, python, raspberry-pi, temperature, windowsiot

I am working on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows IoT. I want to connect the Raspberry Pi with a [MAX31855 Thermocouple Sensor](https://learn.adafruit.com/max31855-thermocouple-python-library/overview) which I bought on Adafruit. There's a Python libary available on [GitHub](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MAX31855) to read the current temperature from the sensor. Unfortunately, I am not able to get this libary to work on my Pi because I have no idea how to install the prerequisite RPi.GPIO and the Adafruit_Python_MAX31855 libary on my Pi. I am not sure if it is working at all with Python on Windows IoT. Can somebody confirm this?

I've found the thread [Getting SPI temperature data from outside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038788/getting-spi-temperature-data-from-outside-of-class) on StackOverflow which seems to be what I want to do. First, when I connect my Thermocouple with my Pi, do I need to use [Software SPI or Hardware SPI](https://learn.adafruit.com/max31855-thermocouple-python-library?view=all#hardware)? Is there a important difference when working on Windows IoT?

There's also a C++ libary on [GitHub](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MAX31855-library). Is it possible to call the methods from this libary within my C# project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some porting work before using that python driver on raspberry pi with windows IoT core,

1. Follow this sample https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/pythonblinky to get started with python programming on windows IoT.
2. See to Platform.py from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO , it is intended for board version detect and multiple board support. Add it to your project, you can hard-code it to only support raspberry pi.
3. Add MAX31855.py to your project, copy the code from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MAX31855/blob/master/Adafruit_MAX31855/MAX31855.py
4. Replace

   `import Adafruit_GPIO as GPIO`
   with `import _wingpio as gpio`

and `import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI` with `import _winspi as SPI`

Also, replace every api calls with one from [PyWinDevices](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/master/PyWinDevices) library.

5. depending if you're using the [Software SPI or Hardware SPI](https://learn.adafruit.com/max31855-thermocouple-python-library/hardware) wiring, you may need to port SPI.py driver from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/blob/master/Adafruit_GPIO/SPI.py. That SetBang api is the software wrapper for sw/hw spi controller, you can easily write your own following the example.

You shall be good to go after all the driver porting.

Comment: Thank you for your post! Unfortunately, I have no idea how to replace the following api calls with the one from PyWinDevices: `gpio = GPIO.get_platform_gpio()` and `self._spi = SPI.BitBang(gpio, clk, None, do, cs)`. I checked the API from the libary (https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/master/PyWinDevices/docs/_winspi.txt and https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/master/PyWinDevices/docs/_wingpio.txt) but I couldn't find any appropriate method. I'm using software SPI at the moment, is this possible with the windows libary?.

Comment: The sample is using the software SPI https://learn.adafruit.com/max31855-thermocouple-python-library/hardware, essentially, it's using the GPIO controller to generate the SPI clk, mosi, cs, etc signals. So you'll need to port the low-level Adafruit_Python_GPIO driver as well. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I managed it with hardware SPI. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The MAX31855 uses an SPI interface so you can use the [Windows.Devices.Spi.SpiDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.spi.spidevice.aspx) class to read the data in C#.

Here's a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) sample app demonstrating using the SPI bus: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/IoT-SPI

Be aware that SPI may be broken in the latest Windows 10 IoT Core Insider Preview version 10.0.14366.0.  The following thread concerns the MAX31855 and mentions this issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7a61a59-3238-47a3-9249-a3e00abd1488/trouble-reading-thermocouple-max31855-over-spi?forum=WindowsIoT