# Using Thermocouple with Raspberry Pi running Windows IoT

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, sensors, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I am planning to develop a temperature monitoring system for sub zero temperatures. I have done a bit of research and decided the best way forward is to use the Raspberry Pi 3 with the Windows 10 IoT operating system, combined with a Thermocouple and the MAX31855 thermocouple amplifier.

I am new to development on the Raspberry Pi and I am struggling to find any tutorials on how to use the thermocouple with windows 10 IoT effectively. There are countless tutorials on using the thermocouple and MAX31855, but I am unsure if i will be able to use the librarys and processing code that these tutorials offer due to the operating system that I am using.

Is it advisable/suitable to continue with this plan of development or should I use a different operating system.

The main reason I am using Windows 10 IoT is that I am going to connect the Raspberry Pis to Azure using the IoT hub.

Thank you in Advance, any input is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159448/read-temperature-with-max31855-thermocouple-sensor-on-windows-iot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right path.

For the record, if your purpose is to connect to Azure IoT hub, you don't necessarily use Windows IoT Core. the Azure IoT SDK has various platform support, you can easily cross-build for embedded Linux as well.

Back to MAX31855 for IoT, the link CSharpRocks provides has somehow unofficial library for this sensor using SPI bus connection. If you want to use it with Windows IoT Core, you need to port the library. To be specific, you need to replace every call with spi controller with the SpiController UWP provides, which shouldn't be much work though.

To sum up, two options,

1. Use Linux distribution(raspbian etc...), the [library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MAX31855) for MAX31855, and compile/cross-compile [iot-hub-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/c), you can find tutorial for cross-compiling on the repository.
2. Use Windows IoT Core, so that you have native support for Azure IoT Hub, but you need to port the library for MAX31855 for windows platform.

Comment: Thank you very Much. Appreciate the help.